# Event receiver in SharePoint 2010

Tags: event-receivers

I am working on creating an event receiver.  Does SharePoint have a stipulation that the event receiver should be a farm solution or a sandbox solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231562.aspx) msdn article in sandbox allowed item, list and web event receivers.